# Pass negative number -1 to method with literal number type 1| -1 from html error

Tags: html, angular, typescript

my html:

```
<button (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event, -1)"></button>
```

my ts:

```
  onMouseDown(e: MouseEvent, direction: 1|-1) {
    this.compute.emit(direction);
    this._mouseDown.next({e, direction});
  }
```

When I pass argument 1 to onMouseDown everything is ok
When I pass -1 to onMouseDown aot compilation through an error:

> number-control.component.html(11,11): : Argument of type 'number' is
>   not assignable to parameter of type 'vector'

It seems html cant understand literaltype. How I can deal with it?

Comment: direction: 1|-1  ->    direction: number

Comment: Marc, thank you for an answer. I should limit derection by only 1 and -1

Comment: there's no such type as 1 | -1, just put direction: number , and if you want to make sure that the inputs are -1 or 1, make a conditional at the start of the function.

Comment: why I cant use literal numeric type (https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) ?

Comment: The code you posted works as expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kudoxs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Nosheep it's a union type [it definitely exists](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAJglgJygXigRigHygWjQbgFgAoEgYwHsA7AZ2CgA8AuWRFdI4y2+kF+JKjydudKAC9+bVABYATJyA)

Comment: @Stefan, aot compilation through an error

Comment: Why would anyone want to close or downvote this question? It is clearly a new reproducible error.

Comment: @Michael D maybe you want to explain this error and think about solution?

Comment: @tatamingi: I am not sure why Ivy conflicts with Union here. All the more reason to leave the question open.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, Angular Ivy conflicts with the Union Type definition. Disabling it would be a workaround. Try the following

tsconfig.ts

```js
{
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false,
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I use view engine

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

HTML

```
<button (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event, 1)">DIRECTION</button>

OR

<button (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)">DIRECTION</button>
```

TS

```
onMouseDown(e: MouseEvent, direction = -1) {
    this.compute.emit(direction);
    this._mouseDown.next({e, direction});
  }
```